# Date_format conversion is adding 1 year to the border dates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, date-format, unix-timestamp

When I use DATE_FORMAT for Dec 31st date
2018 year is getting changed to 2019. Can someone help say if this is a bug or I am missing something.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

*`spark.sql("select CAST(1546268400 AS TIMESTAMP)").show(false)`*

**Output:** 2018-12-31 15:00:00.0

---

*`spark.sql("select DATE_FORMAT(CAST(1546268400 AS TIMESTAMP), 'MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm')").show(false)`*

**Output:** 12/31/***2019*** 15:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Spark shell Results]

So this doesn't *exactly* answer your question but the use of `YYYY` vs `yyyy` seems crucial here. Still investigating actually, but this might help you to figure it out as well.

Update:
https://github.com/davedelong/calendar_fallacies/issues/26

The distinction between `YYYY` and `yyyy` is ISO_Week Year vs calendar year.